# Kafka-Connect Sink configuration enable.auto.commit vs offset.flush.interval.ms

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to understand the behavior of how offsets are committed, from what I read offsets are automatically committed after completion of put(when the next put is called)

The question I have is how the following parameters influence this?

- offset.flush.interval.ms (default is 60 seconds)
- enable.auto.commit and auto.commit.interval.ms (default is 5 seconds)

1. Meaning if commits are done when next put is called are they queued and actually only done every offset.flush.interval.ms?
2. If enable.auto.commit=true does this mean auto.commit.interval.ms is used instead?

Sidenote:
From reading kafka documentation the consumer config enable.auto.commit defaults to true. But when i ran my File Sink connector in both strimzi apache kafka-connect and confluenct-kafka-connect i see that when the connector comes up the enable.auto.commit is set to false.

Comment: Kafka Connect doesn't use auto-commit because it breaks delivery guarantees and tracks offsets separately

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you for the reply, this is what I was looking for :) is there any documentation for this?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Besides, you can always override client properties in connect if you really needed to change it